# "Like" or "have liked"?

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, present-tense

Is this sentence correct?

> From early ages people like travelling.

Isn't it better to say:

> Since early ages people have liked travelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need some indication of the past tense.  You could keep a semblance of the first version by saying something like the following:

> "People like travelling" has been true since early times.

But I agree that the second version is much better.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's definitely better to say

> Since the early ages, people have liked traveling.

Because, ***have liked*** implies that people ***used to*** and still do, like traveling.

Answer (score -2):

How about "People love to travel. It's been true since Moses crossed the waters."

Comment: wow, that sounds perfect! :)